# Connecting to Peered VPC with a VPN connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc, google-cloud-networking

I have setup two VPC's (VPCA 10.102.0.0/16 and VPCB 10.103.0.0/16) on google compute cloud and VPCA is peered with VPCB.

I have setup a VPN connection from my office (10.101.0.0/16)  where I work to VPCA.

I want to access the instances on VPCB from my office.

I have already setup a static route from the office network to VPCB.

How do I go about doing this...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some restrictions in the VPC network peering. One of them is VPNs are not reachable across the peered VPC networks. You can see this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering#vpns_not_reachable_across_peered_networks) to find more information about the restrictions of VPC network peering.

If you want to access VPCB from your office, you have to create another VPN tunnel between them.

Answer (score 0):

At the hybrid connection, you need to export custom routes so that the On-premises side will know how to reach peered VPC Networks. Please refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/knowledge/kb/not-able-to-use-hybrid-connectivity-of-the-peer-vpc-network-000004738) for further details